# `npm cache add <tgz>` does not work

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cache

I pack an NPM library with:

```
tarball=$(npm pack)
```

then I run

```
npm cache add "$PWD/$tarball"
```

but when I inspect the npm cache in `.npm`, there's nothing new there.

Does anyone know why the NPM cache would not get updated by the add command?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the very same problem on Windows2012 machine when using npm version 5.3.0. Moving on to 5.6.0 it is no longer a problem.